# when is a linear transformation invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

i know about the theorem that for a linear operator $T:V\to V$ to be invertible its enough to prove that its one to one. but does that apply to other transformations like $T:U\to V$ where $U$ does not equal $V$ but they have the same dimension?

Comment: Hint: can you encode a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a quadratic polynomial and back? Certainly those two spaces are different, but are they similarly structured?

Comment: Is there any difference? In general we need both injection and surjection, but if dimensions are the same (in your example $U = V$), then injection implies surjection.

Comment: Look carefully at the nullity-rank theorem.

Comment: This is part of something more general.  Any transform linear or not will be invertible if and only if it is bijective.  This is essentially true by definition.

Comment: This is OK if $U,V$ have finite dimension (which the OP did not state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This is only true for finite dimensional vector spaces.

If $F:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation, then $F$ invertible means it’s an isomorphism. Any isomorphism must be injective and surjective, and in the case of sets with an algebraic structure (like vector spaces) that’s actually sufficient.

So if $F$ is invertible then it is injective and surjective, but by the rank nullity theorem, which states:

$$\dim \text{im }F+\dim\ker F=\dim V$$

So if $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension, it is actually sufficient to check that $F$ is either injective or surjective, as if $F$ is injective then rank nullity implies that $\text{im } F=W$, so $F$ is surjective, and if $F$ is surjective then rank nullity implies that $\ker F=0$ so $F$ would be injective.

You could also choose a basis for $V$ and $W$, write $F$ as a matrix with respect to this basis, and then take the determinant of $F$. If this is non zero then $F$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Point out that you assume **finite dimension** for your spaces.

Comment: @GEdgar yes of course my bad thank you